# Strange query results from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I'm testing on my database, but for some weird reason, and randomly, it returns a different set of results. Interestingly, there are only two distinct result-sets that it returns, from thousands of rows, and the query will randomly return one or the other, but nothing else.

Is there a reason the query only returns one of two datasets? Query and schema below.

My goal is to select the fastest laps for a given track, in a given time period, but only the fastest lap for each user (so there are always 10 different users in the top 10).

Most of the time the correct results are returned, but randomly, a totally different result set is returned.

```
SELECT `lap`.`ID`, `lap`.`qualificationTime`, `lap`.`userId` 
FROM `lap` 
WHERE (lap.trackID =4)
AND (lap.raceDateTime >=  "2013-07-25 10:00:00")
AND (lap.raceDateTime <  "2013-08-04 23:59:59")
AND (isTestLap =0)
GROUP BY  `userId` 
ORDER BY  `qualificationTime` ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lap` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `trackId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `raceDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
    `qualificationTime` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `isTestLap` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
```

(DB create script trimmed of un-needed columns)

Comment: Do you need ID's of fastest laps, or just duration?

Comment: @Uriil I actually only need the IDs - the qualificationTime and userId rows are just being selected for debugging this issue

Comment: What if two laps of same user have same duration?

Comment: @Uriil The business rules for the game prevent this from happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a (mis)feature of MySQL called hidden columns.  As others have pointed out, you are allowed to put columns in the `select` statement that are not in the `group by`.  But, the returned values are arbitrary, and not even guaranteed to be the same from one run to the next.

The solution is to find the max qualification time for each user.  Then join this information back to get the other fields.  Here is one way:

```
select l.*
from (SELECT userId, min(qualificationtime) as minqf
      FROM lap
      WHERE (lap.trackID =4)
      AND (lap.raceDateTime >=  "2013-07-25 10:00:00")
      AND (lap.raceDateTime <  "2013-08-04 23:59:59")
      AND (isTestLap =0)
      GROUP BY  `userId` 
     ) lu join
     lap l
     on lu.minqf = l.qualificationtime
ORDER BY  l.`qualificationTime` ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Does mean the sub-query is run for every lap in the table? I had something similar in my original query, but it wasn't scaling properly which is why I took the route of separating it into two queries. Your query above takes 0.2 seconds to run. Do you think it'd scale as the lap table and number of users grows?

Comment: @dKen . . . I think the query will be ok.  But, scaling is interesting (always is).  If you have a composite index on `TrackId, IsTestLap, raceDateTime`, then the performance should scale ok.  Otherwise, it will need to scan the entire lap table before doing the aggregation.  If performance becomes an issue, ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting `lap.ID`, `lap.qualificationTime` and `lap.userId`, but you are not `GROUPing BY` them. You can *only* select fields you group by, or else aggregate functions on the other fields (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc). Otherwise, results are undefined.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan. Do you happen to have an idea what I should do to fix this then? Normally I'd have an idea, but I'm lost in this case

Comment: Sure. What do you want in your result set? A set of rows, each with a userId and... what else?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just need the ID of the lap actually (the qualificationTime and userId were just there for debugging). I'll need to take those IDs later on and use them to get a bunch more information.

Comment: So assuming you want all the non-test laps run on track 4 on a specific date, you could simply `SELECT distinct`, or use `GROUP BY` indeed. Something like: `SELECT distinct(ID) FROM lap WHERE (... your conditions here)` and that's it.

Comment: Well, I need the fastest laps (non-test, track 4, specific date) for the top 10 different users. There could be one user that has the fastest 5 laps, but I need just their fastest lap, and 9 other laps for the next 9 fastest users. I need the laps of the fastest 10 unique users, if that makes sense?

Comment: Having read all the other comments, esp. yours about speed, I think you need to 1) consider your index structure (at the very least add an index on userId,track) 2) go with analytical functions (read up on `window functions` or `analytical functions` in PG guide 3) divide into 2 queries. If that makes sense I can elaborate more.

Comment: No no, you're spot on. I have already indexed the table heavily, but I think the sub-query was killing me even with the indexes. Your third point about separating it into two queries I agree with as well, and that is what lead me to this SO question. Absolutely makes sense

Comment: btw, here's an interesting approach (one that could be very fast): use your original query, but remove the `GROUP BY`, and increase the `LIMIT` very much. Increase it to, say, 1000. Add an index on trackId and raceDate at the very least. Possibly also on the qualificationTime, and if there are many test laps then also on isTestLap. Now you get a long list of rows, some with the same userId. Use code (or another query) to extract just the best lap for each user. Its a heuristic, but one that works 99.99% of the time, and is very fast.

Comment: Great "alternative" solution - I'll definitely check that out and see how it would work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that sometimes values for `lap`.`ID`, `lap`.`qualificationTime` are different. And it's right behaviour for mysql. Because you group by `userId` and you don't know what values for other fields will be returned. Mysql can select different values depend on first value or last rows reading.

Comment: thanks Andrej, have you got an idea how I could alter my query to return the correct results?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be your ORDER BY on a decimal entity, and how the DB stores this and then retrieves it.

Answer (score 0):

I would check something like this:

```
   SELECT  `l1`.`qualificationTime`, `l1`.`userId`,
          (SELECT l2.ID FROM `lap` AS l2 WHERE l2.`userId` = l1.userId AND 
          l2.qualificationTime = min(l1.`qualificationTime`))
   FROM `lap` AS `l1`
   WHERE (l1.trackID =4)
          AND (l1.raceDateTime >=  "2013-07-25 10:00:00")
          AND (l1.raceDateTime <  "2013-08-04 23:59:59")
          AND (isTestLap =0)
   GROUP BY  `userId`
   ORDER BY  `qualificationTime` ASC
   LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I started with, and now I'm getting into the 1,000s of rows and users, the sub-query is killing me. It runs the sub-query for every user (which could be thousands), then only picks the top 10 afterwards. It's too inefficient, which is why I'm trying the different route above.